# Yii's CJuiDatePicker doesn't work for me

Tags: php, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I copied the Yii documentation's example for `CJuiDatePicker`:

`$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name'=>'publishDate',
    // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;'
    ),
));`

The form field is rendered, but when I click it nothing happens, no calendar is displayed.
Am I missing something? do I have to manually include JQuery, or set some javascript callbacks or anything else than the example above?

Comment: The widget should make sure that JUI and jQuery are included. You should provide more information if you can. Get Firebug and see if any errors occur. Also, look at the source being output - make sure that jQuery etc IS included, and make sure that the call to datepicker() has the right selector for the input field (the same #id - #publishDate probably)

Comment: thanks @thaddeusmpt . I included jquery twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my fault.
There was a .htaccess with deny from all, preventing the page from loading the Jquery files from the /assets dir.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same when the corresponding CSS file was missing. The calendar did appear although far beyond the boundaries of the window.